# Shared data between iOS devices

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing an internal iOS cocoa app, in which multiple devices need to connect and read/write to a data connection.  It will be similar to an inventory application.

Would this be best done using a server-side SQLLite communicator or some other kind of server-side data store?  Or is there a method i don't know of that multiple devices can share data.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A third-party service possibly worth checking out is [Parse](https://parse.com/).

> With Parse, you can add a scalable and powerful backend in minutes and launch a full-featured app in record time without ever worrying about server management. We offer push notifications, social integration, data storage, and the ability to add rich custom logic to your app’s backend with Cloud Code.

Comment: Thanks!  Parse looks like it is exactly what i needed.  I was researching building a web-service from scratch but it seems to already be done for me here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the complexity and assuming that all devices can be connected to the same icloud account you could utliize icloud for this.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1