# ioS: How to share data between two devices which are far way?

Tags: ios7, data-sharing

In one of my application I need to share 4 (Datatype:double) values to another device. As per my requirements I don't use BackEnd server. Can anyone suggest me a best way to achieve this? Here we have one more glitch is the distance between the devices may be long also.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285305/share-data-across-multiple-apps-on-ios
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103411/shared-data-between-ios-devices

Comment: if that would be possible without back-end in general, the big VOIP providers immediately can stop their own servers to use such technology. :)

Comment: @holex, Yes you are right.